# Get-ExchangeServer from Exchange 2010 does not return Exchange 2013 server in output

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2010

I have an Exchange org with 2x Exchange 2007 servers, 1x Exchange 2010 server and 1x Exchange 2013 server.

On the 2007 and 2013 servers running Get-ExchangeServer cmdlet outputs all four servers. On the 2010 server Get-ExchangeServer cmdlet only outputs the 2007 and 2010 servers.

Is this expected behaviour from the 2010 server or is it indicative of some issue in the environment somewhere?

On Exchange 2010 Server;

```
[PS] > Get-ExchangeServer
Name                Site                 ServerRole  Edition     AdminDisplayVersion
----                ----                 ----------  -------     -------------------
BC-EXCH07           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
BC-EXCH10           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 14.3 (Bu...
BC-EXCH07-2         bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
```

On Exchange 2007 and 2013 Servers;

```
[PS] > Get-ExchangeServer
Name                Site                 ServerRole  Edition     AdminDisplayVersion
----                ----                 ----------  -------     -------------------
BC-EXCH07           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
BC-EXCH10           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 14.3 (Bu...
BC-EXCH07-2         bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
BC-EXCH13           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Standard    Version 15.0 (Bu...
```

Interestingly, if I run Get-ExchangeServer -Identity * on the Exchange 2010 Server I do get the full set of four servers in the output. I'm not sure why this is.

```
[PS] > Get-ExchangeServer -Identity *
Name                Site                 ServerRole  Edition     AdminDisplayVersion
----                ----                 ----------  -------     -------------------
BC-EXCH07           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
BC-EXCH10           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 14.3 (Bu...
BC-EXCH07-2         bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 8.3 (Bui...
BC-EXCH13           bclabs.local/Conf... Mailbox,... Standard    Version 15.0 (Bu...
```

Comment: Did you move the admin mailboxes over to Exch13?

Comment: Try the powershell commands from the new exch 13.
Best option open the rdp , desktop, on the exch 13. If all is setup right the exch 13 should work fine, if it is not then you have to trouble shoot the error fro that point. Jb